# How to Detect the End of Mobile Data Session on Android Phones

Tags: android, session, packet, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I am looking to log the number of Packet Data Sessions an Android phone on 3G or 2G has in a given set of time.

I was hoping that the **TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED** event in the **PhoneStateListeners** corresponds to the end of data sesion but it doesn't , as my operator charges me for a session (*the popUp message which comes after data usage*) after multiple DATA_DISCONNECTED events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the data disconnect event or data connect event.
First you need to add the receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".Networkconncted"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Next you need create a class which extends `BroadcastReceiver`, this class would be called when data is connected/disconnected.

```
public class Networkconncted extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String key = "networkInfo";
    public static final String disconnected = "DISCONNECTED";
    public static final String MOB_INT = "mobile";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.get(key).toString();
            Log.v("netappcheck", value);
            String temp[] = value.split(",");
            if (temp[0].toLowerCase().contains(MOB_INT)) //check if mobile n/w
                if (temp[1].contains(disconnected)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"data disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //do something when data is disconnected
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"data connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //do something when data is connected
                }
        }
    }
}
```

When the broadcastreceiver is called the `intent.getExtras().get(key)` will return the below value:

```
[type: MOBILE[EDGE], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, 
reason: (unspecified), extra: airtelgprs.com, roaming: false, 
failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false]
```

The field in type mentions the type of network is connected, when connected/disconected wifi type will return `WIFI[]`, when connected to mobile network(3G,EDGE etc) the type field will return `MOBILE[]`.

The field in state mentions connectivity state.

The variable temp[] puts the type in 0th position, state in 1st position. We need to check if its `MOBILE` in 0th position as we need to get only to track the mobile network connectivity.Then check the state in the 1st position.

I tested it in Android 5.0.1 and Android 4.0.4 it works fine.
More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)

Comment: Dude, I appreciate your answer but looks like you didnt go through the question before answering it.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you want the count of size or number of times data session connects/disconnects. You would want to clarify the question more

Comment: Dude, data disconnects isnt the same as session disconnects, I dont want to go to the engineering part of it but if you stay in India try using ur code and see how many times u get a data disconnect event before u get a pop up message from ur operator indicating an end of data session. I checked it, its more than once.